# Making change on element

Tags: html, css

I have two `<i>` elements and I want to make a change to the first one only. How can I do that without using a class?

```
<div class="align">
   <h2 class="text-uppercase">Contact Us</h2>
   <p><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>example@gmail.com</p>
   <p><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>000000000</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: What do you mean "not use a class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many css pseudoselectors that could solve this problem. Here's two simple ones:

```
// select a 2nd child element of .align with an <i> inside
.align :nth-child(2) i {
  // rules for the <i> element styling
}
// select the first <p> inside align with an <i> inside
.align p:first-of-type i {
  // rules for the <i> element styling
}
```

You'll just need to make sure that the pattern you use to select is unique so that other elements which are similar don't get picked up.

Comment: to be maximally specific, you can do `div.align > p:first-of-type > i {}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use nth-child(2) which says target p tag that is second child of parent

```css
p:nth-child(2){
color:green;}

p:nth-child(2) i{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
      <h2 class="text-uppercase">Contact Us</h2>
   <p><i class="fas fa-envelope">red</i>example@gmail.com</p>
   <p><i class="fas fa-phone-alt">black</i>000000000</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-of-type()` selectors.

```css
p:nth-of-type(1){color: red;}
```

Comment: can't I target the i element directly with nth-of-type ??

Comment: @EslamAmr No. Because it would be applied to every `<i>` inside of `.align`.